# Android Maps V2 API Center Current Location On Screen

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps, android-location

I am trying to accomplish this simple task, which seemed to be pretty straightforward, but it is still not working as it's supposed to do. I am using the method below, but the phone zooms in the city center, about 2km from where my blue location dot is.

```
public void setUpMap() {
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(context);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));


    }
```

I have tried to set different zoom values, but nothing changes much. I am not sure if I should set up a newLatLngBounds or not, since everyone says this is the right way. It seems I am not getting my current location, but my city's location.

Comment: so you want exact and accurate location on map?

Comment: I want to zoom on my location as much as I want, but when I set the zoom, the camera moves where I am not located, which is pretty strange. In other words, I want to see the blue dot in the center of my phone's display.

Comment: Maybe first location is inaccurate and you are using it to center the map and after that location changed to more accurate. Try implementing OnMyLocationChangeListener and inside it follow changes.

Comment: My code is now working for no reason, I guess the problem is with the method getLastKnownLocation, which was directing me to a place where I was this morning. It's weird, but is there a way to check that lastknownLocation is called after having made an attempt to currentlocation?

Comment: getLastKnownLocation() returns old cached values or even null occasionally. why don't you try LocationClient instead?, getLastLocation() is more accurate than getLastKnownLocation() from LocationManager.

Answer (score 2):

new Answer:-

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                Location myLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();

                if (myLocation != null) {
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation
                                    .getLongitude()), 14));
                }
```

Comment: I get the same result.

Comment: In this case, it zooms out and shows me the initial map with Africa in the center. :\

Comment: it takes little time to fetch your exact location.once its get it,it shows your location.

Comment: It doesn't really move, isn't there a way to use moveCamera as I was trying to do? I really don't get this, it should be really simple.

Answer (score 1):

This is coming a bit too late, but there's 2 ways to go about it.

### FusedLocation API

Implement FusedLocation API (see [Making Your App Location Aware](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)), use it to [setup a location request](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) and obtain a location fix. When you get the Location object in the callback, use it to set the location in the GoogleMap object.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;
     mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 15));
}
```

### OnMyLocationChangeListener

GoogleMap class has a OnMyLocationChangeListener, which you can implement like so for a single fix:

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 15));
            mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(null);
        }
    });
```

The problem is, the interface is [marked as deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener.html) and Google recommends using the FusedLocation API. You could use it if you really want to but be aware of any future API changes making this unusable and breaking your app.